# How do I grab title,description and key words with php?

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

how do I grab title,description and keywords...without `get_meta_tags` function??

Comment: what is the problem with get_meta_tags?

Comment: Title, description and keywords of *what*?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: How to extract specific elements from a website gets asked on a daily basis. You should not have difficulties finding an answer with [the search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DOM+html+[php] "Searches for DOM html [php]").

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this HTML DOM parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

An option:

```
<?php

$database = 'meta_tags.txt';
$meta_db = fopen($database, 'r');

$page = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$page = substr($page, 1);

while($data = fgetcsv($meta_db, 9000, '|'))
{
    if($data[0] == $page)
    {
                $title = $data[1];
        $meta_keywords = $data[2];
        $meta_description = $data[3];
    }
}

?>
```

Taken from:

http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/3640/

Comment: You've just gone to the third Google result for "php meta tags" and pasted the code, without bothering to notice that it's completely meaningless on its own.

Comment: Wow how did you know that!? amazing. Just trying to help. And i provided a link so he could see full code and its alternative to get_meta_tags...

Comment: see I havent done that...after testing various options with meta tags I have seen that for some sites get_meta_tags fucntion taking too long. I am doing a data mining with my 100k website list and when I put it into loops some time one loop is taking more time to complete. this is why and I have read many articles says get_meta_tags delays it so thought will ask for any alternative